# Creating a Game of Falling Random Objects using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am attempting to create a game that will simulate groceries coming down a conveyor belt. The player acts as a bagger and must click and drag the groceries into designated bags (one for cold food and one for non-cold food). When the correct choice is made the food will disappear and the score will increase +1.

I have become overwhelmed by thinking about how to do this and have not found helpful answers that actually work when I try to compile them so I decided to ask.

Can anyone suggest a way or show me how I can have random grocery items fall down the screen? I assumed I could create an array of movieclips and have them be called to fall down randomly, but I am not sure how this would work.

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard for people to give accurate answers since we can't see what you've tried. The way I would do this is create an array of random items. Each item in the array is an instance of a class that describes the grocery(name,cold/non-cold,etc.). This would be roughly the data part, the view would look as described(conveyor belt), but function a lot like a looping carousel component, but using drag/drop to remove an item from it. The controller part would update the model/data with another random element, triggered by the item removal. On item dropped, check bags/update scrore/etc.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not saying what I have tried. I avoided that because I am a beginner AS3 programmer and the things I have tried so far seem completely confusing to me and I figured to others. 

I have tried simply putting different objects on the screen and making them fall downwards using addChild(bread); bread.y += 1; 
I was able to get the startDrag and stopDrag to work as well as the collision with a bag object. I just wanted to find a way to make more objects fall randomly at random intervals. I just don't know how to populate it and make it differentiate between cold/non items.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write the whole game for you but it's not that hard. I got a little piece of code which shows the use of MovieClips in an Array. You could do something with that. The code is not tested, and there are some values you have to correct.

Please let me know if it was helpfull. I use this a lot in my games. It's an easy way of handling lots of bullets / enemies and powerups ;)

```
    var groceries:Array = new Array();

    function grocerieCreate(enemy,shotType):void {

    var grocerieNew:MovieClip;

    grocerieNew = new grocerieMovieClip();
        grocerieNew.x = [Random X];
        grocerieNew.y = 0;

    addChild(grocerieNew);

    grocerieNew.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, grocerieMove);

}

function grocerieMove(e:Event):void {

    if (e.target.y < [GROUND Y]) {          
        e.target.y ++;          
    }

}

function grocerieRemove(e:Event):void {

    for (var counter:int = groceries.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {

        var thisGrocerie:MovieClip = groceries[counter];

        groceries.splice(counter,1);
        removeChild(thisGrocerie);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is definitely a useful way to do what I am attempting and it has taken me in the direction.

Comment: Very welcome. Box2D is cool to use too, but i think in this case it's going to be a bit of an overkill. But that's my opinion. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get realistic falling objects, use [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/), the **AS3 Physics Engine**. It's well documented, and there are literally thousands of tutorials for beginners out there.

EDIT: [Here is a great tutorial for absolute beginners on Box2D](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/01/27/box2d-tutorial-for-the-absolute-beginners/), in Emanuele Feronato's blog. Check out that blog, as it has lots of tutorials on game dev that might help you out.

Comment: Wow... these tutorials are great. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Please note that this tutorial only works with the older version of box2d version 2.02